# Who vs whom in "Who is the right person to turn to?

Tags: pronouns, word-order, grammatical-case, questions, whom

Take the sentence:

> **Who** is the right person to turn to?

I'm not sure whether *who* or *whom* should be used in this position.

Comment: For some reason, you questions causes reruns of Abbott and Costello’s famously hilarious *Who’s on First?* skit to run through my mind.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the easy way to figure out which one is correct. If you answer the question (or substitute the statement) with 'he' and it makes sense, use 'who.'  If 'him' makes sense, use 'whom.' 'Whom' and 'him' both have the letter m so that is how to remember that they go together.

"Whom did you ask?" 
 "I asked him."

"Who answered the question?"
"He answered the question."

"Whom is the right person to turn to?"
"Him is the right person to turn to." => INCORRECT

"Who is the right person to turn to."
"He is the right person to turn to."  => CORRECT

Comment: Really? How will that distinguish 'Who did you ask? I asked him' please?

Comment: Coo! Which helpful people gave me two downpoints for asking that? Could someone explain how Miss Ti's rules cope with *Who did you ask? I asked him* please?

Answer (score 4):

Sure, it's fine.

In fact,
  *Whom is the right person to turn to?*
sounds downright silly, and
  *To whom is the right person to turn?*
is even sillier, if possible.
No native English speaker would ever say either one, at least not in the USA.

The best advice about the use of *whom* is

> **Don't bother to use *whom*. Ever, at all.**
>   *Whom* is [dead](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001437.html). It's an ex-pronoun. It's joined the bleedin' choir invisible.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Not sure if you have watched this movie, but this quote seems really cool to me.

"But to whom, might I ask, am I speaking?" -V for Vendetta. 

What do you think, John?

Comment: I didn't say people didn't use _whom_. I just said that was the best advice to people about how to use it -- Don't. If you **do** use it, be **sure** you understand exactly how it's sposta be used, and why, and in particular have a good reason for why you're using it **now** instead of _who._ Because the use of _whom_ is, in a word, fraught.

Comment: Using *who* for *whom* never bothered anyone (well, I hope) but the reverse is pretentiously hypercorrective — and therefore annoying in the extreme. Considering that not even published authors and professional editors seem to manage to reliably and correctly select one over the other, it seems best to avoid *whom* altogether.  If I read one more “tell whomever is going” or “it’s from whomever figured it out first”, I think I’m going to scream. Better by far that it be altogether banished than that it be used willy nilly with neither sense nor meaning, nor distinction.

Comment: I always suspected "Lawler" was a pseudonym for "Cleese." Now I'm sure!

Comment: I still use whom, at least in writing. I might not in speech but inwardly I feel bad for dumbing down.

Comment: Sorry to hear it; but progress always seems painful for some. I personally would prefer it if English were as inflected as Spanish; pronouncing personal pronouns properly at speed is my particular bête noir. But I digress.

Comment: Yes, dead.  Need not be used.  In the 1970s I was surprised to find this point of view among ESL texts.  But now I (sometimes reluctantly) admit the language changes.

Comment: I didn't expect some kind of Spanish imposition.

Comment: It is true that, in questions, _who_ is killing off _whom_ in everyday conversation. But _who_ cannot replace _whom_ in the sentences such as the following: _The school has 50 teachers, most of whom are bilingual_. And _whom_ cannot be replaced by _who_ in relative clauses starting with a preposition: _He is someone for whom I have great admiration._

Comment: The school has 50 teachers, most of who are bilingual. He is someone who I have great admiration for. Perhaps not standard English, but you can substitute *whom* quite easily with *who* and still be understood.

Comment: But the point is, should you?

Comment: @Mary-Lou. Well, we could often get by with grunts and gestures if comprehensibility is the only necessity. The point is that in certain contexts the reader might react negatively if the writer uses _who_ instead of _whom_. English language exams are one such context and application letters are another. And while you can certainly avoid _whom_ by pushing the preposition to the end of the clause, you might not wish to do so if the clause is long: _He is someone who I have had the greatest respect but very little admiration since my childhood for_.

Comment: Or you can just say _that_ and let somebody else worry about the Objective Case.

Comment: -1 terrible answer.  Oversimplification of the language is not a good thing and can lead to ambiguities.

Comment: Ambiguities are unavoidable and plentiful. They're a feature of all language everywhere. And going by the real rules is not oversimplification; making up silly rules about "correctness" is oversimplification.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous answers in that "whom" is mostly being phased out of regular usage, so I would go with using "who" in this type of sentence. Some further support for "who" over "whom" here is that you are using "who" as a subject (and "whom" is only objective). Here, as in many instances, "is" is a linking verb; it links the description ("the right person to talk to") to the subject ("who"), meaning that both parts, basically, serve the same grammatical function.

For example, if I were to say "I am Michelle," then "I" and "Michelle" are equivalent. The reason your example is a little trickier is due mostly to the fact that we switch word order around in sentence structure, and that's enough to throw anybody off!

Answer (score 1):

> To whom should I turn?

Ex-pronoun, indeed. :)

Comment: *Whom should I turn to?" is formal.  "Who should I turn to?" is normal.  But "To whom should I turn?" is unnatural in the extreme. People do not really talk that way.

Comment: 'To who it may concern'?

Comment: "Whom should I turn to?" is not formal; it is incorrect. "To" is a preposition and therefore cannot end the sentence.